# String to integer leetcode

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I was doing following leetcode question

> Implement `atoi` which converts a string to an integer.
>
> The function first discards as many whitespace characters as necessary
>   until the first non-whitespace character is found. Then, starting from
>   this character, takes an optional initial plus or minus sign followed
>   by as many numerical digits as possible, and interprets them as a
>   numerical value.
>
> The string can contain additional characters after those that form the
>   integral number, which are ignored and have no effect on the behavior
>   of this function.
>
> If the first sequence of non-whitespace characters in str is not a
>   valid integral number, or if no such sequence exists because either
>   str is empty or it contains only whitespace characters, no conversion
>   is performed.
>
> If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned.
>
> Note:
>
> Only the space character ' ' is considered as whitespace character.
>   Assume we are dealing with an environment which could only store
>   integers within the 32-bit signed integer range: [−2<sup>31</sup>,  2<sup>31</sup> − 1]. If
>   the numerical value is out of the range of representable values,
>   INT_MAX (2<sup>31</sup> − 1) or INT_MIN (−2<sup>31</sup>) is returned.

Question link: https://leetcode.com/problems/string-to-integer-atoi/

Here for this input `"-91283472332"`, I am not sure why do they expect the following output `-2147483648` instead of `-91283472332`

Not sure, If this relevant but this is my code

```
/**
 * @param {string} str
 * @return {number}
 */
var myAtoi = function(str) {
    let i = 0
    let output = ''
    let nonWhiteCharacter = false 
    while (i<str.length) {
       const char = str[i]
       if (!char == " ") {
           if (char.toLowerCase() === char.toUpperCase()) {
            if (!nonWhiteCharacter) nonWhiteCharacter = true
               output = output + char
           }  
           if (!nonWhiteCharacter) return 0
       }
        i++
    }
    return output === null ? 0 : parseInt(output)
}
```

Comment: `-91283472332 < -2147483648`, so it's out of bounds for expected output.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure why do they expect the following output -2147483648 instead of -91283472332

Because:

> Assume we are dealing with an environment which could only store integers within the 32-bit signed integer range: [−2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup> − 1]. If the numerical value is out of the range of representable values, INT_MAX (2<sup>31</sup> − 1) or INT_MIN (−2<sup>31</sup>) is returned.

So if the extracted number is larger than `2 ** 31 - 1`, the returned number should be `2 ** 31 - 1` instead.

Similarly, if the extracted number is smaller than `-(2 ** 31)`, instead return `-(2 ** 31)`.

This would probably be easier with a regular expression:

```js
const myAtoi = (str) => {
  const match = str.match(/^ *([+-]?\d+)/);
  if (!match) return;
  const num = Number(match[1]);
  return Math.max(
    Math.min(2 ** 31 - 1, num),
    -(2 ** 31)
  );
};

console.log(
  myAtoi('    123'),
  myAtoi('-456'),
  myAtoi('-9999999999999'),
  myAtoi('9999999999999')
);
```

Comment: Using `Number` is _probably_ cheating.

Comment: Just like in an interview, unless a programming challenge specifically says that certain things are forbidden, I'd prefer to take the quick-to-write, easy-to-read, easy-to-debug route. If more restrictions are added, they can be worked around, but don't create more work for yourself unless it really is the best (or only) option. IMO

Comment: @Luaan technically, probably using JS numerics before capping them to `[2^31, 2^31 - 1]`, since JS numbers handle values outside this range, yet the task says we should assume the environment can't handle out of bounds values. So a *proper* implementation would convert a string to a *minimum* of `-2147483648` and a *maximum* of `2147483647`and won't ever handle an out of bounds value as a number primitive. Yet, as most coding challenge tasks - go only with anything that's explicitly mentioned or checked for and don't do extra code.

Comment: @VLAZ Well, out-of-bounds numbers in JS are supposed to give you positive or negative infinity, which work fine with `Math.min`/`max`, so in that environment it should still work fine.

Comment: @Luaan it's not a JS specific task, though - JS is only one of the languages you can choose to implement it in. And there is no JS environment that only handles 32 bit signed integers - it's part of the JS specifications, after all. If we want to be more global and not specific to JS then we can't guarantee what an over- or underflow would do in all instances. Therefore, if you were to be true to the *spirit* of the task, you'd avoid numbers until the end. But since it's just useless work for a simple coding challenge, it's fine to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look it this solution. As we are dealing with integers, they only hold 32-bit. 2^31 < x <= -2^31. So here we use a try catch as the 32bit integer can raise NumberFormat Exception which will be caught by the catch block.

```
class Solution {
    public int myAtoi(String str) {

        int flag=0, sign = 0;
        int n = str.length();
        StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
        int i =0;

        //clear white spaces
        while(i<n && str.charAt(i) == ' '){
            ++i;
        }

        //overflow of string
        if (i>=n){
            return 0;
        }

        //checking sign and not allowing more than one sign, will return 0 if there is ++,+-,--
        while(i<n && (str.charAt(i) == '+' || str.charAt(i) == '-')){
            if (sign >= 1){
                return 0;
            }
            else{
           st.append((str.charAt(i++) == '+') ? '+': '-');
            sign++;
            }

        }

        //checking if character is digit
        while(i<n && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))){
            st.append(str.charAt(i++));
            flag = 1;
        }

        //return 0 if no digits
        if(flag == 0)
            return 0;

        //to check if the number is within the int range
        try{
            return Integer.parseInt(st.toString());

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return (st.charAt(0) == '-') ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }



    }
}
```